# Swift display firebase data on tableview not shown

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, tableview

im making application with firebase as a database, and i seems cant to show my data to my tableview. i check on my firebase all my data is good even when i add new data the data is immediately shown in my firebase. but seems like thers some miss logic i have here....can someone help me?

*Edit theres 1 line where the code wont work

this is my main controller:

```
class MainController: UITableViewController, AddPatientControllerr {


private var patientLists = [PatientList]() 
var Segue : String = "PatientName"
var Segue2 : String = "PatientNotes"
let user : User = Auth.auth().currentUser! 

private var rootRef : DatabaseReference!// 1. buat nyambung ke root db

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
   
    self.rootRef = Database.database().reference() 
    
    populateList()
    
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self

}

// MARK : Firebase Function

private func populateList() {
    
    self.rootRef.child(self.user.emailWithoutSpecialChar).observe(.value) { (snapshot) in 
        
        self.patientLists.removeAll()
        
        let pasienListDict = snapshot.value as? [String:Any]  ?? [:] 
        
        for (key,_) in pasienListDict {
            
            if let pasienlistdict = pasienListDict[key] as? [String:Any]{

                if let pasienlist = PatientList(pasienlistdict) { // this line of code is not working 
                    self.patientLists.append(pasienlist)
                   
                }else {
                   print("your condition not working")
                }
            }
            
        }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
           self.tableView.reloadData()
       }
        
        
    }
    
}

// MARK : Func delegate

func addPatientData(controller: UIViewController, nama: String, tglLahir: String, Telp: String, berat: String, Tinggi: String, golDarah: String) {
       
    let patientList = PatientList(name: nama, tglLahir: tglLahir, Telp: Telp, berat: berat, Tinggi: Tinggi, golDarah: golDarah)
       self.patientLists.append(patientList)
              
       let userRef = self.rootRef.child(self.user.emailWithoutSpecialChar)
       let patientListRef = userRef.child(patientList.name)
       patientListRef.setValue(patientList.toDictionary())
      
       controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

       DispatchQueue.main.async {
           self.tableView.reloadData()
       }
   }

// MARK : Segue
   
   override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
       
       if segue.identifier == Segue {
           let nc = segue.destination as! UINavigationController
           let addPatientName = nc.viewControllers.first as! ProfileController
           addPatientName.delegate = self
           
           }
           
           else if segue.identifier == Segue2 {
           
           guard let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow else {return}
            
           let nc = segue.destination as! PasienProfileController
           nc.pasien = self.patientLists[indexPath.row]
     
       }
   
   }
 

//MARK : TableView

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .delete {
        let pasienList = self.patientLists[indexPath.row]
        let pasienListRef = self.rootRef.child(pasienList.name)
        pasienListRef.removeValue()
    }
}
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    
    return self.patientLists.count
}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    
    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell") as? MainCell else {return UITableViewCell()}
    let patientListt = self.patientLists[indexPath.row]
    
    cell.NameLbl.text = patientListt.name

    return cell
  }  
}
```

and this is the model where i keep the data and dictionary :

```
import Foundation

typealias JSONDictionary  = [String:Any]

class PatientList { 

var name : String!
var tglLahir : String!
var Telp : String!
var berat : String!
var Tinggi : String!
var golDarah : String!
var patientNote :[PatientNote] = [PatientNote]() //ini buat nyimpen notes2 dari tiap2 pasien 

init(name : String, tglLahir : String, Telp : String, berat : String, Tinggi : String, golDarah : String) {
    self.name = name
    self.tglLahir = tglLahir
    self.berat = berat
    self.Tinggi = Tinggi
    self.golDarah = golDarah
    self.Telp = Telp
}

init?(_ dictionary :[String:Any]){
    
    guard let name = dictionary["Name"] as? String else {
        return nil
    }
    guard let berat = dictionary["BeratBadan"] as? String else {
        return nil
    }
    guard let tglLahir = dictionary["TanggalLahir"] as? String else {
        return nil
    }
    guard let Tinggi = dictionary["TinggiBadan"] as? String else {
        return nil
    }
    guard let golDarah = dictionary["GolonganDarah"] as? String else {
        return nil
    }
    guard let Telp = dictionary["Telefon"] as? String else {
        return nil
    }
    self.name = name
    self.berat = berat
    self.tglLahir = tglLahir
    self.Tinggi = Tinggi
    self.golDarah = golDarah
    self.Telp = Telp
    let pasienListDictionary = dictionary["patientNote"] as? [JSONDictionary]
    
    if let dictionaries = pasienListDictionary {
        self.patientNote = dictionaries.compactMap(PatientNote.init)
    }
}

func toDictionary() -> [String:Any] { // ini buat dictionary buat convery object jd string:any, jd biar ga ngubah satu2 kl ada yg salah gituu
    
    return ["Name":self.name, "BeratBadan":self.berat, "TanggalLahir":self.tglLahir, "TinggiBadan":self.Tinggi, "golDarah":self.golDarah, "Telefon":self.Telp, "patientNote":self.patientNote.map{ patientNote in
        return patientNote.toDictionary()
    }]
}

}
```

and this is my firebase :

[![Firebase][1]][1]

for the starters i just need to show my name into my tableview which in this case i cant even show the name data in my tableview

i cant seems to find out why the data wont show in my tableview....xcode not showing error

anyone can help me? thanks

firebase Json

```
"afipermanalivecom" : {
    "Apiyyy" : {
        "BeratBadan" : "",
        "Name" : "Apiyyy",
        "TanggalLahir" : "20-05-2020",
        "Telefon" : "",
        "TinggiBadan" : "",
        "golDarah" : "A+"
    },
    "CocaCola" : {
        "BeratBadan" : "80",
        "Name" : "CocaCola",
        "TanggalLahir" : "20-06-2020",
        "Telefon" : "0878099996049",
        "TinggiBadan" : "190",
        "golDarah" : "A-"
    },
    "Jamsey" : {
        "BeratBadan" : "",
        "Name" : "Jamsey",
        "TanggalLahir" : "19-06-2020",
        "Telefon" : "",
        "TinggiBadan" : "",
        "golDarah" : "A-"
    }
},

"puffygmailcom" : {
    "Batman" : {
        "Name" : "Batman"
    },
    "Stitchh" : {
        "Name" : "Stitchh"
    }
}
```

Comment: A few things. Most importantly, please don't use email addresses as keys. There are dozens of reasons not to but email addresses change and if that happens, you have to scan, remove and re-write every reference to it in your entire database. Use userId's to reference users, and store that reference as a child node. Please include structures as    *test* in questions so we don't have to re-type all of that if we want to use it in an answer. To get your Firebase structure, use the Firebase console->Export JSON and copy and paste a snippet of your structure.

Comment: This `self.rootRef.child(self.user.emailWithoutSpecialChar).observe(.value)` is going to load the nodes 'CocaCola` and then 'Jamsey` etc all at once (within one big snapshot). Is the objective to get to the child data within each node, e.g. BeratBadan, Name etc? Again though, hard coding keys to real-world names is usually a bad idea, those keys should be created with .childByAutoId since the product name is stored within the node anyway. Please update your question with additional details and clarity, and remove the image and include a text based firebase structure.

Comment: One more thing. You don't need dispatchQueues `DispatchQueue.main.async` in Firebase closures. UI calls are always called on the main thread whereas networking is on a background thread. So that can be removed. :-)

Comment: aaa okayy thanks @jay i will try to implement your advice, cause i just started to learn firebase, and i will update my question with JSON from firebase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the code and structure in the question it appears there's a list of doctors and patients with the patients being child nodes of the doctor. I'll post a solution and then some important recommendations about changes.

Here's the existing Firebase structure. Note that we are NOT using email addresses as node keys - it's a lot of extra work and if the email address changes, the entire database will have be scanned, nodes read, deleted and re-written. Dynamic node keys (ones that could change, like an email) should instead be generated with .childByAutoId - I am using doctor_0, doctor_1 etc for readability.

```
{
  "doctor_0" : {
    "name" : "Dr. Doolittle",
    "patient_list" : {
      "patient_0" : {
        "blood_type" : "O-",
        "name" : "Henry"
      },
      "patient_1" : {
        "blood_type" : "AB-",
        "name" : "Leroy"
      }
    }
  },
  "doctor_1" : {
    "name" : "Dr. McCoy",
    "patient_list" : {
      "patient_2" : {
        "blood_type" : "O+",
        "name" : "Steve"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I have two classes to hold this data, a DoctorClass and PatientClass with the Patient class being an array within the DoctorClass. Note that a Doctor may not have any Patients so I am treating that as an optional.

```
class DoctorClass {
    var doc_id = ""
    var doc_name = ""
    var patients = [PatientClass]()
    
    convenience init(withId: String, andName: String, maybePatientList: DataSnapshot?) {
        self.init()
        self.doc_id = withId
        self.doc_name = andName
        
        if let patientList = maybePatientList {
            let allPatientsSnap = patientList.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot]
            for patientSnap in allPatientsSnap {
                let patient = PatientClass(patientSnap: patientSnap)
                self.patients.append(patient)
            }
        }
    }
}

class PatientClass {
    var patient_id = ""
    var patient_name = ""
    var blood_type = ""
    
    convenience init(patientSnap: DataSnapshot) {
        self.init()
        self.patient_id = patientSnap.key
        self.patient_name = patientSnap.childSnapshot(forPath: "name").value as? String ?? "No Name"
        self.blood_type = patientSnap.childSnapshot(forPath: "blood_type").value as? String ?? "No blood type"
    }
}
```

and finally the code to read in all of the doctors and populate their patient array with their patients.

```
var docAndPatientList = [DoctorClass]()

func loadDoctorsAndPatients() {
    let doctorsRef = self.ref.child("doctors") //self.ref points to *my* firebase
    
    doctorsRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
        let allDoctorsSnapshot = snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot]
        for docSnap in allDoctorsSnapshot {
            let docId = docSnap.key
            let docName = docSnap.childSnapshot(forPath: "name").value as? String ?? ""
            let patientSnap = docSnap.childSnapshot(forPath: "patient_list")
            let doc = DoctorClass(withId: docId, andName: docName, maybePatientList: patientSnap)
            self.docAndPatientList.append(doc)
        }
    })
}
```

and then let's print them out

```
func printDoctorsAndPatients() {
    self.docAndPatientList.forEach { doctor in
        print("Dr: \(doctor.doc_name)")
        for patient in doctor.patients {
            print("  patient: \(patient.patient_name)  bloodtype: \(patient.blood_type)")
        }
    }
}
```

and the output

```
Dr: Dr. Doolittle
  patient: Henry  bloodtype: O-
  patient: Leroy  bloodtype: AB-
Dr: Dr. McCoy
  patient: Steve  bloodtype: O+
```

That will work with the existing structure but what if, for example, a patient has two doctors? Or what if we want to query Firebase for all patients that have blood type O-? It's not going to work (easily) with that structure.

Here's a better plan

```
root_ref
   doctors
      doctor_0
         name : "Dr. Doolittle"
         patients
            patient_0 : true
            patient_1 : true
      doctor_1
         name : "Dr. McCoy"
         patients
            patient_2 : true
```

and patients

```
root_ref
   patients
      patient_0
         blood_type : "O-"
         doctors:
            doctor_0: true
         name : "Henry"
      patient_1
         blood_type : "AB-"
         doctors:
            doctor_0: true
         name : "Leroy"
      patient_2
         blood_type : "O+"
         doctors:
            doctor_1: true
         name : "Steve"
```

This structure provides way more query flexibility and scaleability.

Comment: thanks for this detail answer and code, i really appreciate it and thanks for that json as well.....so i should refactor all of my firebase code and change into using your reference, i will try it first but thanks for the tips mate

Answer (score 0):

Just some tips and perhaps a solution, 
I would recommend using firebase Cloud instead of firebase real time firebase, its much fast and more reliable especially if your trying to query data from arrays or dictionary, I can see you are trying to retrieve data from a dictionary, one thing you want to note is that firebase stores your swift dictionary as an objective C dictionary, so thats one thing you want to note! Try to check if you used the correct reuse identifiers.

Let me know if you still can't get it!

Comment: thanks for the advice sir, even though i still doenst really get it how to implement it cause i learn this firebase apps from udemy tutorial, and i just slightly change the data. from the tutorial he just added one data which is "Name", and it works so i think i wanna add another data like "birthdate, etc". but now the data isnt showing

Comment: @afipermana While answers are appreciated, the answer states that Firestore is 'faster' and 'more reliable' and that is not accurate. In many cases the RTDB blows Firestore away for retrieving data and has an equal amount of reliability. Additionally *firebase stores your swift dictionary as an objective C dictionary* is not accurate as the RTDB isn't Objc, it's JSON data so it doesn't store objects at all. That data can be loaded into a variety of objects within code. To clarify, the NSDictionary is in CODE wheras what's stored in RTDB is json.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to return a list of data, you would have to use `.childAdded` instead of `.value`

So, your code would be something like this:

```
self.rootRef.child(self.user.emailWithoutSpecialChar).observe(.childAdded) { (snapshot) in

       // do your stuff here
}
```

*salam sesama orang Indonesia :)

Comment: aa halo mas makasih udh respon, tp masih blm bisa nih mas codenya datanya ga muncul juga di tableview.....

*indo pride :)

Comment: '.value' returns a list of data. See the getting started guide [Working with Lists of Data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/lists-of-data#listen_for_value_events) for an example. In this case .childAdded iterates over every child node, returning them one at a time, and leaves an observer for new child nodes being added. Whereas `.value` returns all of the nodes within the list at once, and leaves an observer for any new *changes*. So the behavior is different but the end data is the same.